# Split a file and have a specific name for the new splitted files

Tags: bash

I have a file `file_script.txt`  with several lines 
and I would like to divide it with 7500 lines in each new file.txt created. To do so I used : `split -d -l 7500 file_script.txt split_files_script.txt`

and I got:

```
split_files_script_recover.txt00
split_files_script_recover.txt01
split_files_script_recover.txt02
split_files_script_recover.txt03
...
```

But instead of naming these files like that I would like to name them like that:

```
split_files_script_recover01.txt
split_files_script_recover02.txt
split_files_script_recover03.txt
split_files_script_recover04.txt
...
```

Note that the number changed of place and it begins with 01 and not 00.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?

```
split -l 7500 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt file_script.txt split_files_script
```

See `man split`.